# How can I delete all of my Git stashes at once?

Tags: git, git-stash

How can I delete all of my [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) stashes at once?

Specifically I mean, with typing in one command.

Answer (score 3644, accepted):

The following command deletes all your stashes:

```
git stash clear
```

From the [git documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html):

> **`clear`**
>
> Remove all the stashed states.
>
> **IMPORTANT WARNING:** Those states will then be subject to pruning, and may be impossible to recover (...).

Comment: why not git stash drop ?

Comment: @user20358: Because `stash drop` (" _Remove a single stashed state from the stash list. When no <stash> is given, it removes the latest one. (...)_ ") does not answer the question (" _How can I delete **all** of my Git stashes at once?_ ")?

Comment: @Tadeck, ok, `stash drop` *removes a single stashed state*. But `stash clear` has this *Note that those states will then be subject to pruning, and may be impossible to recover*. And `stash drop` doesn't have that text. So one can easily think that these commands don't do the same thing and have some big differece.

Comment: In addition to what accepted answer mentioned - `git stash clear`, to confirm if all cleared, use - `git stash list`

Comment: @Ryan: `git help <command>` is the best way to get documentation (and, it's actually pretty good). In this case, `git help stash` clearly show that `git stash clear` does the deed (this didn't stop me from coming to SO first and upvoting the answer... but that tells you more about me than `git` :D )

Comment: extending @kamal comments, if using  `git stash list` simply moves the cursor to the next line without any output then you can be assured that all stashes are removed.

Comment: `stash clear` will also hard reset your branch, which is just lovely when you have about 10 fiddly config changes active... oof.

Answer (score 165):

This command enables you to look all stashed changes:

```sh
git stash list
```

Here is the following command use it to clear all of your stashed changes:

```sh
git stash clear
```

Now if you want to delete one of the stashed changes from stash area:

```sh
git stash drop stash@{index} # Index will be shown after getting stash list
```

Note: `git stash list` enables you to get index from stash area of git.

Comment: Worth mentioning that at least for the integrated terminal in VSCode using Windows 10, it is `git stash drop 'stash@{index}'`, with apostrophes.

Answer (score 99):

There are two ways to delete a stash:

1. If you no longer need a particular stash, you can delete it with: `$ git stash drop <stash_id>`.
2. You can delete all of your stashes from the repo with: `$ git stash clear`.

Use both of them with caution, it maybe is difficult to revert the once deleted stashes.

Here is the [reference article](https://kolosek.com/git-stash/).

Comment: Closing the terminal has nothing to do with it.  git isn't a daemon; it only runs when you call it. It has no idea you closed the terminal.

Comment: re: closing the terminal.  I noticed there is a diagnostic message that prints: Dropped stash@{1} (hashid) and perhaps that can be useful to recover the stash.

Answer (score 45):

I wanted to keep a few recent stashes, but delete everything else.

Because all stashes get renumbered when you drop one, this is actually easy to do with while.  To delete all stashes older than stash@{19}:

```sh
while git stash drop 'stash@{20}'; do true; done
```

Comment: Does this apply to indexed values introduced in Git 2.11, where you can refer to the 3rd stash from the stash list using `git stash pop 3` instead? I wanted to know if we can use the `while` loop and drop stashes using index values.

Comment: I love the simplicity of this, nice elegant solution!

Comment: Can I do something to keep some stashes in between the provided list. Like in your case it will delete all after 19. So for e.g. in btw 19 and last stash I have 2,3 stashes like at 23,25 that I need to keep.

Comment: Or I can provide a range like stash indexes 20-30. @warp

Answer (score 34):

Clear all stashes at once

```
    git stash clear
```

List all stashes

```
    git stash list
```

delete specific stash

```
    git stash drop stash@{index}
```

Answer (score 23):

To delete all stashes older than 40 days, use:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=40.days refs/stash
```

Add `--dry-run` to see which stashes are deleted.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44829516/946850 for an explanation and much more detail.

Answer (score 14):

If you hit “**git stash list**” you will get the list of shashes.

[image]

**Remove the stashes:**

1)Delete only some selected stash, then run the below command:

```
git stash drop stash@{index}
```

2)Delete the complete list in one go, run the following command:

```
  git stash clear
```

Answer (score 11):

> **if you want to remove the latest stash or at any particular index** -

**git stash drop type_your_index**

```
> git stash list

  stash@{0}: abc
  stash@{1}: xyz
  stash@{1}: pqr

> git stash drop 0

  Dropped refs/stash@{0}

> git stash list

  stash@{0}: xyz
  stash@{1}: pqr
```

> **if you want to remove all the stash at once** -

```
> git stash clear
>

> git stash list
>
```

***Warning*** : Once done you can not revert back your stash

Answer (score 10):

Clear all stash from the list:

```
git stash clear
```

Clear particular index from the list:

```
git stash drop index
```

Answer (score 6):

I had another requirement like only few stash have to be removed, below code would be helpful in that case.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 5 8`
do
   git stash drop stash@{$i}
done
```

/* will delete from 5 to 8 index*/

Comment: try `for iterator in \`seq 5 8\`; git stash drop stash@{$iterator}; done`

Comment: Note that when you drop, the remaining stashes move up 1 spot.  So if you want to remove from 5 to 8, you need to either count backwards or remove stash@{5} four times.  For example:  `for i in \`seq 4\`; do git stash drop 'stash@{5}'; done`

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to clear the latest stash or
even you created a stash with **git stash create** then
you should simply use

```
git stash drop
```

but if you want to clear all the git stashes of the current git repository
then you can use

```
git stash clear
```

WARNING: Those states will then be subject to pruning(knock off), and maybe impossible to recover

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with VSCode, the 1.64 (Jan. 2022) will include `git stash clear` in its commands.

See [issue 123375](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123375) and [commit 302c41c](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/302c41cf4e4c3de5afa8583f6da68248cea0ae86):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26203420/117556727-437aa600-b06c-11eb-9db6-ed80896b12f6.png]

> ```
> "command": "git.stashDropAll",
> ```