# Remove parts of our bloated git history

Tags: git

**My Problem:**

Early on when the repository was set up a mistake was made causing all the images at the time to be written to the repository. This was quickly rectified in the gitignore file and no longer presents a problem.

The problem is now that we have an enormous repository which contains the history of the images. This presents a problem when cloning the repository locally as it takes a lot longer than a clean clone from the tip.

**My questions:**

Is there a way of removing the part of the history that includes the images which are never going to be needed?

If I cannot remove can I compress or even cleanup the history in any way?

Comment: Checkout [6.4 Git Tools - Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html), especially the part *The Nuclear Option: filter-branch*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New repo with copied history of only currently tracked files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901588/new-repo-with-copied-history-of-only-currently-tracked-files), [Completely remove unwanted file from Git repository history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-unwanted-file-from-git-repository-history), and [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history/872700#872700).

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake, the second link provided part of the answer I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is removing part of history - you use `git rebase interactive`

if it is file removal (from all versions) use `git filter-branch`