# [Git]How to extract history of specific file[s] and write out to new empty branch?

Tags: git

At most, A file in git repository has history that includes many commits.
Now, I want to extract file[s] with all history that can trace from `HEAD`(with same AuthorDate/CommitDate), and want to write out to new empty branch(able to create with `git checkout --orphan`).

I know that `git filter-branch` has potential to do that, however, I don't know how because it is too powerful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just branch off of the old branch and **remove** excessive files in that new branch using `git filter-branch`. After removing unnecessary files in the new branch you'll have two branches — the old branch untouched and the new branch with the files that you want. The history in the new branch will be preserved (actually, recreated) by `git filter-branch`.

Comment: How to specify files that want to remove on `git filter-branch`?

Comment: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file1 file2…'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/872565/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17993505/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=git+filter-branch+remove+files

Comment: Thank you! I used  BFG Repo-Cleaner and followed your approach. After that, I use git rebase to remove empty commit caused by BFG Repo-Cleaner.