# clean git history of deleted files, keeping renamed files history

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-branch

I'd like to extract some files to a new repo, keeping their history, **including files renaming**.

Best and closest answer I could find was [new-repo-with-copied-history-of-only-currently-tracked-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901588/new-repo-with-copied-history-of-only-currently-tracked-files), using `git filter-branch --index-filter`. It successfully keeps history of existing files, but it doesn't preserve history of renamed files.

(Another answer I could find was using `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`. But it has two issues: doesn't seem to work for the whole repo (folder '.') and doesn't preserve history of renamed files.)

(Yet another answer was using `git subtree`. But it doesn't keep history at all.)

So I'm probably looking for a way to improve the `git ls-files > keep-these.txt` command from closest answer to also **list all previous file names**. Maybe a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't store file name changes.

Each commit stores a complete tree, e.g., perhaps commit `1234567...` has files `README` and `foo.txt` and commit fedcba9... has files `readme.txt` and `foo`.  If you ask git to compare commit `1234567` to commit `fedcba9`, and `README` is sufficiently similar<sup>1</sup> to `readme.txt`, git will say that the way to transform the one commit to the other is to rename the file.  (If the one commit is the parent of the other, `git show` of the child commit will show the rename, because `git show` computes this change at `git show` time.)

On the other hand, if the second `readme` file is too different, but `README` is sufficiently similar to `foo`, git will say that the way to change `1234567` to achieve `fedcba9` is to rename `README` to `foo`.

The key is that git computes that *when you ask for the comparison*, and not a moment earlier.  There's nothing in between the commits that says "rename some files".  Git simply compares the commits and decides *then* whether the files are similar enough.

For your purposes, what this ultimately means is that for each commit in your sequence-of-commits-to-copy-or-partially-copy, you'll have to decide which path names to keep and which to discard.  How to achieve that is mostly up to you.  The `git log` command does have a `--follow` flag to activate a limited amount of rename detection as it works backwards from child commits to their parents, and `git blame` automatically tries to do the same; you could use these (one path name at a time) to come up with a mapping of the form:

```
      in:   commits A..B    C..D             E..F
use path:   dir/file.ext    dir/frill.txt    lib/frill.next
```

for instance.  But there's nothing built in to do this, and it won't be particularly easy.  I'd start by combining `git log --follow` with `--raw` or `--name-status` output and seeing if there are any interesting Renames detected.  If and when there are, those are the commit boundaries at which you'll want to change which paths you're keeping and discarding as you work through commits (whether that's with `filter-branch` or some other method).

If that doesn't work, or you need more control, consider running `git diff --name-status` between various commit pairs (with commit pair info coming from `git rev-list`).

---

<sup>1</sup>As long as you've asked for rename detection, "exactly the same" is sufficiently similar, as is anything down to about "50% similar".  You can tweak the required similarity with the optional value you supply to `git diff`'s `-M` flag.

---

**Edit**: this seems to work OK.  I used it on git's own `builtin/var.c`, which used to have two previous names according to this:

```
$ git log --follow --raw --diff-filter=R --pretty=format:%H builtin/var.c
81b50f3ce40bfdd66e5d967bf82be001039a9a98
:100644 100644 2280518... 2280518... R100       builtin-var.c   builtin/var.c

55b6745d633b9501576eb02183da0b0fb1cee964
:100644 100644 d9892f8... 2280518... R096       var.c   builtin-var.c
```

The `--diff-filter` suppresses everything but rename outputs so that we get to see which commit seems to rename the file.  Turning this into something more useful requires a bit more work, but this might get you fairly far:

```
git log --follow --raw --diff-filter=R --pretty=format:%H builtin/var.c |
while true; do
    if ! read hash; then break; fi
    IFS=$'\t' read mode_etc oldname newname
    read blankline
    echo in $hash, rename $oldname to $newname
done
```

which produced:

```
in 81b50f3ce40bfdd66e5d967bf82be001039a9a98, rename builtin-var.c to builtin/var.c
in 55b6745d633b9501576eb02183da0b0fb1cee964, rename var.c to builtin-var.c
```

Comment: Can you provide a script for listing the previous file names? I can't figure out how to do it, and I have hundreds of files to deal with, so can't manually analyze logs one file at a time. Default 50% similar is fine for me.

Comment: Thanks to you, I got the list of old filenames with `git ls-files | while read -r line; do (git log --follow --raw --diff-filter=R --pretty=format:%H "$line" | while true; do if ! read hash; then break; fi; IFS=$'\t' read mode_etc oldname newname; read blankline; echo $oldname; done); done`