# git show to view prior version of a renamed file?

Tags: git, git-show

We renamed a file where `git log --follow my/new-file` correctly shows changes before and after the rename.

But this command does not work to show a prior version: `git show <rev>:my/new-file`.

We have to run `git show <rev>:my/old-file`.

Is there a way you can run this command with my/**new**-file instead of my/**old**-file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is easy, if displeasing: no.

The problem here is that `git show` first resolves what to show (via `git rev-parse`, more or less), then shows it, and `git rev-parse` does not walk through history trying to follow a file and do a diff from each commit to its parent(s) to see if it can find what looks like a rename.

Using `git log --follow`, however, does precisely that: look at each commit compared to parent commit(s), generate a diff, and see if the resulting diff suggests that perhaps `my/new-file` was renamed from `my/old-file` at that time.  If so, it adjusts its next-older check to work with `my/old-file`.

Git could perhaps use a separate program (or mode in `git log`) that looks to see if some file(s) were renamed across some commit-pair(s), and if so, provide the previous path to other git utilities like `git show`.  Then you could say: `git show $(git whatwas HEAD <rev> my/new-file)`, or something like that (depending on the details of this hypothetical `git whatwas` command did).  You could write a script that  essentially performs this `whatwas` using the technique I outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33865903/1256452).  I'm sure various annoying details would crop up in the process, but the theory seems reasonable.