# How to remove history after splitting git repo

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, revision-history

I've split a git repo using

```
$ git clone bigrepo smallrepo
$ cd smallrepo
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subdir/ master
```

Now the smallrepo now has the history related to subdir on the master branch, `git log` only shows this history, and `git branch --all` only lists the master branch. However, in SourceTree, the smallrepo still has history not related to subdir on a separate, unnamed branch.

Questions:

- How do I get rid of this extra history so that smallrepo is a clean repo that only has the history related to subdir?
- Why does this extra history show up in SourceTree but not on the command line?
- Is there a better way to split a git repo?
- (Bonus question) Is there a way to split a git repo by file name rather than subdirectory (the file may have changed subdirectory at some point) and keep the history related to the file?

Comment: Well, I found a solution that worked for me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901588/new-repo-with-copied-history-of-only-currently-tracked-files). However, it takes a different approach by first deleting all the file in the repo and then restoring only those files that I want to keep. Since this only addresses my 3rd question (subjectively), I won't "answer my own question".