# Delete stashed changes older than X days

Tags: git

How could I delete all stashes older than X days?

I use `git stash` in my everyday workflow, which means I end up with months of old stashes.

Comment: Maybe your workflow should start using `git stash pop` instead of `git stash apply`?

Comment: `git stash list --before="x days ago"` lists all the stashes before x days. Then `git stash drop` them one by one.`git stash list` have some options that work for `git log`. Maybe there is a single git-stash subcommand that can drop them all.

Comment: `git stash drop stash{@x.days.ago}` generally deletes one stash X days ago. Not sure how to work around to delete all stashes..
may be `git stash drop stash{@x.days.ago..n}`
*Disclaimer: I've not tried this.*

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try this tonight and report back!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Use `git reflog expire` manually

The underlying mechanism for "pushed" stashes—i.e., any stash whose name is not just `stash` or `stash@{0}`, but rather `stash@{1}`, `stash@{2}`, and so on—is Git's *reflogs*.  The reflog records the *previous value* of a reference, whenever the reference changes.  (I'll define *reference* below, and complete the definition of the *reflog* there.)

Most reflog entries expire on their own, through the configurable `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` settings (see both [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) and [the `git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html)).  The `refs/stash` reference, however, is special: by default, its entries *never* expire, rather than expiring after 30 or 90 days.

You can run `git reflog expire` manually and override any of these.  For instance:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=40.days refs/stash
```

tells Git to expire any stash entries, all of which are always unreachable (see below for details), that are at least 40 days old.  Add `--dry-run` to the options to see which ones would expire, without actually expiring them ... though there is a minor flaw here: it does not print their *numbers*, i.e., it never says that it's going to toss, say, `stash@{17}`.

#### References and reflogs

Git's *references* are a generalization of branch names, tag names, remote-tracking branch names, and all those other names that Git has.  A reference simply translates a name—something like `master` or `v1.2` or `stash`—to one of Git's internal hash IDs.

A branch name is just a reference whose *full* name starts with `refs/heads/`.  A tag name is just a reference whose full name starts with `refs/tags/`.  A remote-tracking branch name is a reference whose full name starts with `refs/remotes/` (and then has the name of the remote and another slash).

Some reference names, particularly branches, change quite often.  For instance, your `master` branch, which is really `refs/heads/master`, changes every time you add a new commit to `master`.  Whenever Git replaces the stored hash value for a reference, it may—depending on whether reflogs are turned on—save the *previous* hash value.  These saved entries are your *reflogs*.

Each reflog entry has a time stamp.  Reflog entries eventually age out and get expired, so that you do not wind up with thousands or millions of reflog entries.

#### Reachable and unreachable, and why they're not applicable for `refs/stash`

Branch names normally move in a forward fashion, e.g., one commit at a time.  That is, we add *new* commits to a branch, and all the *old* commits that were on that branch are still on the branch.  Sometimes we will pick up commits en-masse and add them all at once, in a "fast" forward fashion: all the new commits are on the branch, and all the old commits are also still on the branch.  The branch name points to the *tip* commit on the branch, the right-most `o` in this diagram:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch
```

We add more commits, and the branch name still points to the tip:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- branch
```

but since each commit points back to its *parent* commit, *all* these commits are *reachable*.

Sometimes, though, we deliberately *remove* a commit, and replace it with another.  For instance, if we have commits we have not pushed, we can use `git commit --amend` or `git rebase -i` to make some changes.  When we do that, the old ones don't go away just get.  Instead, they get shoved to the side:

```
...--o--o--X   <-- branch
```

becomes:

```
          X ...... branch@{1}
         /
...--o--o--Y   <-- branch
```

where `Y` is our replacement for `X`.

Note that the parent commit of `Y` is not `X`, but rather `X`'s parent.  This means commit `X` is *not* reachable from `Y`.

The two separate "reflogExpire" configuration items, for reachable and unreachable objects, refer to commits that can be found by starting at the *current* value of the reference—for our branch named `branch`, that's `refs/heads/branch`—and working backwards.  Commit `Y` is reachable, and so are the `o`s, but `X` is not.  If there is a reflog entry pointing to one of the earlier `o`s, it's *reachable*, but `branch@{1}` points to `X` which is *unreachable*.

Git's designers essentially believe that unreachable commits are less worthy, so their reflog entries should expire sooner.  Thus, the default is 30 days for *unreachable* entries, and 90 days for the reachable ones.

The `refs/stash` reference, though, does not advance normally at all.  Instead, it points to the current stash, which is a sort of bag-on-the-side: a commit—actually at least two commits and sometimes more—that is not on any branch (I call this a "stash bag"; see [How to recover from "git stash save --all"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452)).  This, in turn, means that *no* previous `stash@{n}` is reachable from the current `refs/stash`, ever!  Every stash reflog entry is therefore unreachable at all times.

Comment: Wooowww. Thanks!

Comment: Added a reply to https://stackoverflow.com/q/11369375/946850 that asks about deleting all stashes, pointing here.